# Aptitude file contents

Tags: command-line, apt, package-management, gedit, aptitude

I ran `sudo gedit /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/00aptitude` o access the aptitude file. I wasn't sure what it was at first and might have changed its contents unknowingly.
The first line was the only one there. I'm not sure what it was.
Through a bit of research I adjusted it to `Aptitude::Get-Root-Command "sudo:/usr/bin/sudo";' >> ~/.aptitude/config`

I get these errors in the terminal when I save it -

```
** (gedit:6378): WARNING **: 12:29:54.898: Set document metadata failed: Setting attribute metadata::gedit-spell-language not supported

** (gedit:6378): WARNING **: 12:29:54.899: Set document metadata failed: Setting attribute metadata::gedit-encoding not supported
```

Comment: Please edit your post and explicitly state your question.

Comment: Those are warnings not errors. You can ignore them. All that matters is whether you can still install and update things using apt.